# Unable to collapse div using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a link,When that link clicked then show Hidden div content.But the problem is next time click i need to Collapse the div.

Here is my Hidden DIV

```
 <div id="divHiddenContainer" style="display: none;">
 <div id="divItem1"> <span">
 </span></div>
```

Here is the Link

```
<a href="#1" class="aItemLnk" id="a1">Read More</a>
```

Here is Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".aItemLnk").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");
    var contentTobeLoaded = $("#divItem" + id).html();

    $('#ajax').html(contentTobeLoaded).fadeIn(100000, function () {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do mine.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            $('.dragbox')
            .each(function () {
                $(this).hover(function () {
                    $(this).find('h2').addClass('collapse');
                }, function () {
                    $(this).find('h2').removeClass('collapse');
                })
                .find('h2').hover(function () {
                    $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }, function () {
                    $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                })
                .click(function () {
                    $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
                })
                .end()
                .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dragbox" id="Widget2" runat="server">
            <h2 style="font-size: 14pt">Heading Goes Here</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content">
                //Information Here
            </div>
        </div>
```

So when you click on the Header (h2), it hides and when you click on it again, it is visible. You will also need some css.. here is mine.

**CSS**

```
.column{
    width:49%;
    margin-right:.5%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:#e2e2e2;
    float:left;
}
.column .dragbox{
    margin:5px 2px  20px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.column .dragbox h2{
    margin:0;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    color:#000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    font-family:Verdana;
    cursor:move;
}
.dragbox-content{
    background:#fff;
    min-height:100px; margin:5px;
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', Verdana; font-size:0.8em; line-height:1.5em;
}
.column  .placeholder{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border:1px dashed #ddd;
}
.dragbox h2.collapse{
    background:#f0f0f0 url("../Images/collapse.png") no-repeat top right;
}
.dragbox h2 .configure{
    font-size:11px; font-weight:normal;
    margin-right:30px; float:right;
}
```

I use the 'dragbox' in a sortable jquery as well. So as you can tell, you will not need the .columns, but I showed them just incase you go that route and would like to use div's as columns. If you do, all you need to do is add

```
<div class="column" id="column1" runat="server">
</div>
```

And then place the 'dragbox' within that. You can have 2 of these 'columns'

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition (if, else) to call fadeIn when the div is hidden, and fadeOut when the div is shown!

Because your code only call fadeIn so the first time, it will fadeIn and the next call it will also fadeIn, so it will stay there.

I don't know in JQuery but that's how I do it in javascript to know if the div is shown or hidden:

```
if(div.style.display == 'block') {
} 
    //call fadeOut
else {
    //call fadeIn
}
```

Comment: actually not in the fadeout,i just wanted to hide that div..How to get second click ?

Comment: What do you mean? if the div is hidden you want to show it and if it's there you want to hid it? And what do you mean by second click? you don't need to worry about it if you call fadeIn fadeOut in a if, elseif.

Comment: if you want to hide it without fadeOut you can do div.style.display = 'none'; if that's your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use fadeToggle instead:

```
$(".aItemLnk").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/^.(\s+)?/, "");
    var contentTobeLoaded = $("#divItem" + id).html();

    $('#ajax').html(contentTobeLoaded).fadeToggle(100000, function () {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toggle method for your desired div inside the click event of a hyperlink.

I've made an example for you in this fiddle > jsfiddle.net/MK68L

Hope it helps